# mysql not returning records

Tags: mysql, select, corruption

Very simple test case, reproduced on different MySQL servers:

```
create table toto (cn decimal(20,2));

insert into toto values(27015040002.00);
insert into toto values(27015040004.00);

select * from toto where cn in('27015040002','27015040004');
```

The select returns the first row, not the second one. Note that the where clause has string values (not decimal). I would expect the select to return all rows or none at all if no conversion is possible - but not half of them.

Comment: This works on SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2908/1.

Comment: what version of your mysql? This is works on mysql 5.3

Comment: You are right. It fails on several mysql 5.1.51 instances. I just tried on a 5.5 server and both records are correctly returned.